# Google cloud speech to text error - Discord bot JDA

Tags: kotlin, google-api, discord, speech, google-voice

I am trying to connect a discord bot with google speech to text, everything was going absolutely swimmingly until I stumbled upon the following error:
https://hatebin.com/siubackdof
This is spammed in the console non-stop. I am unsure how I can resolve this issue.

Here is my code:
https://hatebin.com/zrwbpppkep

Thanks lads